# Change permissions of wheel to Read Only

Tags: macos, terminal

How do I do the following using the terminal on mac os x?:

> Change permissions of wheel to Read Only in
>   /System/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext

Comment: Which OS version as El Capitan will be more complex - also why are you wanting got do this as there might be a better way - changing Apple OS files is usually a bad way todo things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OS X versions before 10.11

```
sudo chmod g-wx /System/Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext
```

For 10.11 you'll need to disable SIP first.